# Is a GARCH a Bilinear model also?

Tags: linear, nonlinear-regression, garch

Following this quote from a 4* econometrics journal,

> "Note that a linear conditional mean model with ARCH disturbances can
> be described by a nonlinear specification without ARCH, i.e. the
> bilinear model. In this paper, we assume that the conditional mean is
> linear and is correctly specifed in the simulations to follow."

See the full paper [here](https://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/econom/v101y2001i1p25-35.html).

However, I seem to have some conflicting information here,

http://economia.unipv.it/pagp/pagine_personali/erossi-old/note32004a.pdf

Who say,

> In contrast with the ARCH model in which the conditional variance is
> time varying, in the bilinear model the conditional variance is
> constant.

***In regards to a bilinear model, if the conditional variance is constant how can this characterize ARCH effects.***

A bonus answer would show how I could simulate a bilinear GARCH model.